# How to fix the SharePoint Online Public CDN Access Denied HTTPS/HTTP error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-powershell, cdn, public-cdn

When setting up the SPO Public CDN using PnP PowerShell, a 403 error shows when trying to access the URL.  It shows an HTTP address instead of an HTTPS address.  In SPfx, a 406 error shows from a JS fetch call.

Here's the setup process:

1. Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName
2. Set-SPOTenant -PublicCdnEnabled $true
3. Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl "Sites/SiteName/SiteAssets/CDN"
4. Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl "Sites/SiteName/CDN"
5. Upload test.css to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/CDN/Files/
6. Make a public link to the file.
7. Upload test.css to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/SiteAssets/CDN/Files/
8. Make a public link to the file.
9. Browse to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/publiccdn.ashx/url?itemurl=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SiteName/CDN/Files/test.css
10. Capture returned URL: https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/1937006161eeae8fe.../Files/test.css
11. Browse to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/publiccdn.ashx/url?itemurl=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SiteName/SiteAssets/CDN/Files/test.css
12. Capture returned URL: https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/2347006161eeae8fe.../Files/test.css
13. Browser to public CDN: https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/1937006161eeae8fe.../Files/test.css
14. Get HTTP 403 error:

**Access Denied**

You don't have permission to access "http://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/1937006161eeae8fe.../Files/test.css" on this server. **(shows HTTP instead of HTTPS)**

Reference #18.2eec3817.1654696621.25fdf7ed

---

The same error happens for the SiteAssets public link.  Why is SPO forcing HTTP on public CDNs?

I also tried the following commands, which provided the same results:

Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl "Sites/SiteName/SiteAssets/CDN"

Add-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl "Sites/SiteName/CDN"

Also tried making public links to the CDN folder and Files folder.

Documentation says you can only access the URL from within SPO, but in an SPfx solution, trying to access a public CDN URL renders an HTTP 406 error.  Here are two GitHub tickets that have not been resolved that are exactly related:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6039

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5981

I'm really trying to get JSON data, and have tried to fetch the data as a MIME file JSON, CSS, TXT, and JPG.  A different project allows me to use PNPjs to fetch JSON from a SP document library.  This public CDN approach to allow data to pull centralized JSON into multiple extranet client sites has me stomped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think the "Access Denied" error is misleading. It was a "referer" related issue and looks like the message used to be "Invalid referer.". I used Postman to send a GET request after including the following KEY and VALUE within the headers and successfully got the file back.

**KEY**: Referer
**VALUE**: https://tenantname.sharepoint.com

And here is the URL of my GET request:
https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/cdn/MyDocLib/Sample.txt